# Migrating a website to a new domain, and associated google index problem

Tags: web, seo, relocation

We currently have a website at "somedomain.net/codefest". We do not own this server (or this domain name).

Due to capacity problems, we are now moving to a new server. Since we do not own the old domain name, we are also moving to a new domain name.

Since we'll need to abandon the old server soon, we'll be redirecting all requests to "somedomain.net/codefest/anything" to "newdomain.net/anything".

My problem is, after a lot of effort, our website's page rank is now fairly significant. I'm sure moving our website to a new domain name will be drastically detrimental to our website's search engine rank.

Is there any way we can tell the search bots that we've moved the website? Perhaps, when I redirect from the old site, if I give a 302 redirect, search spiders will notice it?

Is there any other issue related to moving our website that I should be aware of?

Thanks,
jrh

Comment: thanks people. btw, is this "not programming related"? I think it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google recommend a 301 redirect. (301 indicates permanent change. 302 indicates a temporary change.)

They have other advice on their [Moving Your Site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105) FAQ page which should be more widely applicable than just Google.

Comment: Definitely use a 301 redirect. By doing so, you are politely requesting search engines to donate all esteem from the original URI to the new URI. If you can be more specific with your 301 redirects that will help... i.e. redirect "somedomain.net/codefest/page1.html" to "newdomain.net/codefest/page1.html" so each page redirects to the correct new page (not just to the new home page).

Comment: 301 means permanent, 302 means temporary, you have them backwards

Comment: @Sohnee yes, i'll set up a one-to-one redirect

Comment: @David Dorward, whoops. Fixed now. Thanks.